# How can I hide a window WITHOUT Visibility property?

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog, window

I have an application that has a lot of modal popup windows. Some are custom windows displayed with `.ShowDialog()`, other are generic message boxes using a 3rd party tool (`DXMessageBox.Show(...)`), and others are system dialogs such as an `OpenFileDialog`. If the user leaves the application running long enough, it should time out and show a "Session Locked" screen and prevent users from seeing or interacting with the application until they login again. This is problematic because of the modal dialogs.

My current solution is to host the Relogin screen in the current modal window if there is one, and hide all other windows. The problem is that if I set `Visibility = Hidden` on any window I have called using `.ShowDialog()`, it treats that dialog as having received a result and processes the code that handles the dialog result. They are also no longer modal after they are re-shown.

So my current attempt is to try to hide the window using something other than Visibility, and prevent it from being activated. The closest I've come is by setting `Minimized=true` and `ShowInTaskbar=false`, but this results in an undesirable minimized titlebar above my taskbar.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to prevent this from happening, or alternatively is there another way to hide a window and prevent it's activation without causing `.ShowDialog` to return?

Here's some code to re-create a sample application to test this with. Just add a button to launch the `ShowLock_Click` event handler.

```
private readonly Dictionary<System.Windows.Window, WindowStyle> _hiddenWindows = new Dictionary<System.Windows.Window, WindowStyle>();

// Create a button to launch this for testing
private void ShowLock_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Will show another window with .ShowDialog, then 2s timeout will trigger lock window
    using (new System.Threading.Timer(OnLockTimerElapsed, null, 2000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite))
    {
        ShowTestDialog();
    }
}

private void OnLockTimerElapsed(object state)
{
    _hiddenWindows.Clear();

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        DispatcherPriority.Background,
        new Action(() =>
        {
            var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            Window host = null;
            foreach (Window win in Application.Current.Windows)
            {
                if (IsModalDialog(win))
                    host = win;

                _hiddenWindows.Add(win, win.WindowStyle);

                // Been testing various ways to hide window without using Visibility
                win.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                win.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
                win.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
                win.Opacity -= 1;
                win.IsHitTestVisible = false;
            }
            ShowLockScreen(host);
        }));
}

private void ShowLockScreen(Window owner = null)
{
    var lockScreen = new Window
    {
        Title = "Relogin Window",
        Content = "This is a test Relogin Window. Close Window via X to continue",
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen
    };

    if (owner != null)
        lockScreen.Owner = owner;

    lockScreen.ShowDialog();

    // Once that window closes, restore other windows
    RestoreSession();
}
private void RestoreSession()
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        DispatcherPriority.Background,
        new Action(() =>
        {
            foreach (var win in _hiddenWindows.Keys)
            {
                win.ShowInTaskbar = true;
                win.WindowStyle = _hiddenWindows[win];
                win.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                win.IsHitTestVisible = true;
                win.Opacity += 1;
            }
        }));
}
private void ShowTestDialog()
{
    var test = new Window
    {
        Title = "Test Modal Dialog",
        Content = "This is a test Modal Dialog. Close window via X to continue.",
        Height = 100,
        Width = 350,
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner,
        Owner = this
    };
    var result = test.ShowDialog();

    // This code gets run if I set Visibility=Hidden. I do not want that.
    MessageBox.Show($"Test Dialog result returned. Result : {result}. This should ONLY happen when you click X on the dialog window");
}
private static bool IsModalDialog(Window window)
{
    return (bool)typeof(System.Windows.Window)
        .GetField("_showingAsDialog", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        .GetValue(window);
}
```

Comment: I would write a template for all windows which overlays the content with a login screen when the app is in the timed out state.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I thought about that, but there's a large variety of modal dialogs displayed. Some are custom Windows, others are system dialog boxes (using 3rd party DevExpress), such as `DXMessageBox.Show(...)`, and others are things like OpenFileDialog. I'm not sure a template would work in all cases. I've updated my question with that information as well.

Comment: if its a window you can do something like this `Left="-5000"  Height="0" Width="0"` it will move the window to left so that it won't be on screen. I think for Dialog box also you can move them out of the screen.

Comment: @AvinashReddy I originally tested it and Maximized windows and FileDialogs wouldn't shift off screen. Re-testing it now, and setting `WindowState = Normal` works for Maximized windows, but file dialogs are still not shifting correctly. Perhaps I can use a combination of the two though...

Comment: @Rachel yes if the  `WindowState="Maximized"` it will not work. it work with .`WindowState="Normal"` so once the user is left for too long WindowState="Normal" Left="-5000" Height="0" Width="0"` will remove the window from screen once he login again we can set them back to normal.

Comment: @AvinashReddy It is working for Maximized windows, but not FileDialogs. If you change `ShowTestDialog()` in the sample code to create an `OpenFileDialog`, you can see how it behaves. The file dialog doesn't actually show up in the list of open windows, and `IsModalDialog` actually returns false so it's not recording a modal dialog window as being open at all. I think I can use this though... if no modal dialogs, hide via `Visibility` (this works for FileDialogs), and if there are, hide by shifting off screen.

Comment: @Rachel I have Checked with `OpenFileDialog` im not able to hide it." think I can use this though... if no modal dialogs, hide via Visibility (this works for FileDialogs), and if there are, hide by shifting off screen" Meas ur problem is resloved?

Comment: @AvinashReddy I think so, I am testing a little more and ran into a snag where if I restore visibility, the window isn't activating. To hide FileDialogs, I am both setting Visibility and calling Minimize. Just setting Visibility alone isn't working.